# I can't select MF on credit card

Tags: smartcard

I'm trying the following APDU:

```
00 A4 00 00   02 3F 00  00
```

Everything is according to ISO 7816-4 (7.1.1), but execution fails with SW 0x6A86 (Incorrect parameters P1-P2)

Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Standard states as follows:

> If P1 is set to '00', then the card knows whether the file to select
>   is the MF, a DF or an EF, either because of a specific encoding of the
>   file identifier, or because of the command processing context.
>
> ...
>
> If P2 is set to '00' and the command data field absent or set to '3F00', then the MF shall be selected.

I checked all my Visa/MC cards and this APDU fails on all of them.

Comment: I have an idea: There are no MF on EMV card at all, ISO 7816-4 allows that (section 5.3, Figure 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but difficult to understand without this background:

Smartcard are either native cards (these have a file system including MF, of course) or Javacards / Open Plattform cards (which have none). The Select command that both types share, is select by AID (application ID), i. e. selecting an application (P1 = 4, command data field contains AID). EMV compliant cards can be realized on both, but apparently you have only the latter.